# Doesn't start up properly after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, grub2

I cannot enter my desktop after an update last night.
I realize that they was add another release version(lines) in the GRUB.
How can I fix the problem?
should I run update again using recovery mode? If so, how?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Is it a clean install or an upgraded one from an earlier release (to see if you have grub or grub2)?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10. It was clean install. GRUB 1.98

Comment: I got message [20130654] vboxdrv: Warning :2.6.31+ kernel detected [20.13656] vboxdrv: counter framework which can generate NMIs is active. [20.13659] vboxdrv: the usage of hardware performance conters by [20.13659] vboxdrv: echo 2> /proc/sys/kernel/perf_counter_paranoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was problem with my graphic card driver.
all going well after using default driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have a laptop Acer 4552 with a GPU ATI HD 4250 and after I upgrade from my former kernel to the current I run into this trouble.

I resolved the issue by doing the following:

1. boot on recovery mode in the low graphic mode
2. Because I have already my driver downloaded I just run the configuration and the reboot. This will cause the GPU driver to be updated to the current kernel and then be able to boot.

Updating my kernel also fixed my hang up problem when I put on suspension and be able to use it again.